# If any mathematical expression in a string form and in list, how are you going to solve it in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = ['2','+','3']
for i in s:
    if i == '+':
        w = int(i+1)+int(i-1)
print(w)
```

The error occurred which is obvious.

Comment: First welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The for your problem and how to possibly solve it, why not iterate over the list using *indexes* instead of elements? Or possibly transform the list into postfix or prefix notation where you can then easily use the list as a stack. It all really depends on how generic you want to make your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve any mathematical expression which is in string and list format. You first should know that how the Infix/Postfix notations works for mathematical expression evaluations using stack. If you don't want to use them then just scan list from left to right and do operations like below and you can modify it for multiple operators according to your requirements.

```
s = ['2','+','3','-','5']
ans=int(s[0])
i=1
while(i<len(s)-1):
    if(s[i]=='+'):
        ans +=int(s[i+1])
    elif(s[i]=='-'):
        ans -=int(s[i+1])
    elif(s[i]=='*'):
        ans *=int(s[i+1])
    elif(s[i]=='/'):
        ans /=int(s[i+1])
    i+=1    
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have confidence the string is something that can be evaluated then one possibility is a concatenation of your list back into string form by `''.join()` followed by an evaluation.

```
eval(''.join(s))
```

will do. But if you have more complicated expressions, e.g.

```
s = ['e','^','2']
```

then you'll need rules to interpret `^`, say with `np.power`, and `e` as `np.exp`.